# Regular expression to check occurrence of a word that starts with character '@' in java

Tags: java, android, regex

I am trying to search for occurrence of a word starts with '@', Say **@steve**. But I have no success.

What I have tried so far is this ".*\b@steve\b.*" but  **\b** matches only words which starts with [a-zA-Z0-9_].

If the question is too broad or anybody needs a code sample please let me know I'll post

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: explain *What I have tried so far is this ".\b@steve\b." but \b matches only words which starts with [a-zA-Z0-9_].*

Comment: Why not use `String#startsWith()`?. You should show exact input and expected output

Comment: can you also post the input string/file where you are searching for this?

Comment: @SilentMonk - You should ask for clarification **before you post an answer**

Comment: @TheLostMind, Yeah, sorry. I thought I understood the requirement until 4castle's comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct, a `\b` can't find a word-boundary there because `@` isn't a word character. You could use a look-behind:

```
(?<!\\w)@steve\\b
```

[Regex101 Example](https://regex101.com/r/sI4hJ5/2)

A general case regex would simply be:

```
(?<!\\w)@\\w+
```

Note that in the above regex, the ending `\b` is unnecessary because the quantifier will go to the end of the word anyway.

Comment: Won't work if the text starts with the `@`. Use `(?<=^|\\W)@\\w+`, i.e. `@` sign at beginning of input or preceded by non-word character, then of course followed by one or more word characters.

Comment: @Andreas That's actually the answer I had initially, but it works fine without that check because if it's the start of the string, then the previous character definitely won't be a word-character, and so it'll still match.

Comment: Hi I have tried (?<!\\w)@steve\\b but java string.matches function is returning false 
String I tried is String str="@steve Regex to find a specific word in a string";  str.matches("(?<!\\w)@steve\\b")

Comment: You could also use `\\B`

Comment: @Android_developer This regex is for *finding* a match, not to check if an *entire string* matches the regex, so you can't use `String.matches()` or `Matcher.matches()`. Use `p = Pattern.compile(regex); m = p.matcher(str); while (m.find()) { ... }` to find *all the matches* in the given string.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
(?<!\w)@\w+

This matches @Steve but doesn't match Hello@Steve.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

`@\b\w+\b`

You can test regexes [here](http://regexr.com/)

Comment: It may as well be `@\w+\b` because it's guaranteed to be a word boundary there. However, I think they are trying to validate that the character before is not a word character.

Comment: @4castle, true. I have asked for the input string from the OP. I will modify it based on the reply. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    char[] word = "@SomeWord".toCharArray();
    if (word[0] == '@')
    {
        System.out.println("Starts with @");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Not Starts with @");
    }

}
```

Comment: What if he has a lengthy string which contains lots of @steve.?

Comment: @Raghavendra but the question is just to check the starting character.

Comment: @PankajDubey This regex is used for searching, not validating, so the starting character won't necessarily be the `@`. The match could be somewhere else in the string.